# K&R exercise 1.17

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxWordLength 100
#define working puts("working");

int getline1(char _line[], int _maxWordLength);
void copy(char to[][maxWordLength], char from[], int _rowCounter);


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[maxWordLength];
    char moreThanEightySet[maxWordLength][maxWordLength];                                       //2D array to store lines with characters more than eighty   

    int r_length;  
    int rowCounter = 0;
    int i, j = 0;

    while((r_length = getline1( line, maxWordLength)) > 0)
    {   
        if(r_length > 5)    //5 for testing the condition
        {
            copy( moreThanEightySet, line, rowCounter); 
            rowCounter++;
        }   
    }

    for(i = 0; i < rowCounter; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %s", moreThanEightySet[rowCounter]);
    }


    return 0;
}
int getline1(char _line[], int _maxWordLength)                                                  //reads line inputs and returns the number of characters
{
    int i, c;


    for(i = 0 ; i < _maxWordLength - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' ; i++)
    {
        _line[i] = c;
    }

    if(c == '\n')
    {
        _line[i + 1] = '\n' ;
    }

    _line[i + 1] = '\0' ;

    return i;
}
void copy(char to[][maxWordLength], char from[], int _rowCounter)   
{

    int i = 0;

    while((to[_rowCounter][i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
    to[_rowCounter][i + 1] = '\0' ;
}
```

i am following K&R at this point multi dimensonal arrays have not yet been introduced but i want to experiment and used 2d arrays to store the the lines that are greater than 80 characters is this the correct way to use 2d arrays? and i am getting an segmentation fault can anyone point out where is the mistake taking place 
Thank You

P.S i have edited the program based on the comments and for some reason the 2d array seam to print nothing

Comment: Remove `if(c == '\0')`, change `copy( moreThanEightySet[maxWordLength][maxWordLength], line, rowCounter);` to `copy( moreThanEightySet, line, rowCounter);` and `int i;` to `int i = 0;` (In the `copy` function) and `_line[i + 1]` to `_line[i]`. Oh. You forgot to increment `rowCounter` from the loop in `main`. There are some other problems in `getline1` too for some inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found below line problematic which could lead you to segmentation fault

```
copy( moreThanEightySet[maxWordLength][maxWordLength], line, rowCounter);
```

There are basicaaly two problems with this line .
1) moreThanEightySet[100][100]// maxWordLength =100 as you define it .
Please understand when you define a array like this , it will start from index 0 to 99 **not 100** .index **100** is invalid .So , you could access this array till moreThanEightySet[99][99](which will be the last element) .
In above line you are trying to access  moreThanEightySet[100][100] //which is not valid and may lead you to segmentation fault .

2) signature of copy function is as below :

```
void copy(char to[maxWordLength][maxWordLength], char from[], int _rowCounter)
```

which means it will accept one 2-d array and one 1-d array and one integer but when you calling this function , see what are you passing as first argument .

```
 copy( moreThanEightySet[maxWordLength][maxWordLength], line, rowCounter);
```

First agrument is elemnt at moreThanEightySet[100][100] .It is not 2-d array .Inside copy function you are writing on this value .

**Solution:**
copy( moreThanEightySet, line, rowCounter);//pass the array not specific element

Few more problems I have identified in copy function .

```
void copy(char to[maxWordLength][maxWordLength], char from[], int _rowCounter)  
{

    int i; //undefined value of i .I think it should be 0 .

    while((to[_rowCounter][i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
    _rowCounter++;  //you should not increment rowcounter here as it is not doing anything .Ideally you should increment _rowCounter from the position you are calling this function "copy" 
}
```

see the comments in above function .

```
 while((r_length = getline1( line, maxWordLength)) > 0)
    {   
        if(r_length > 80)
            copy( moreThanEightySet[maxWordLength][maxWordLength], line, rowCounter);
rowCounter++;//you should increment counter here .       
    }
```

I hope this will help .

Comment: For the interest of completeness, there is no guarantee that `_line[i]` contains a `'\0'` character... yet `printf("%s", ...);` requires that there be one.

Comment: Also, a good piece of advice to add at the start of this answer would be suggesting use of tools like `valgrind`...

Comment: thanks i already got that i was thinking to delete the question

Comment: @sachin i got another problem can you try to help me either the array 'moreThanEightySet' is not taking in the value or it is not printing properly i'm not able to figure it out

Comment: Thanks @Seb for your suggestions .Surely valgrind would help in indentifying memory leaks and access violation issue .I personally think we can avoid basic problem by just looking at the code , especially in a smaller code which OP has asked .

Comment: @anveshmydg : Welcome . yup  I would try to help .I have just found two more problems in your code and i have updated the answer .could you check answer now .There is a problem with rawcounter and variable "i" in copy function .

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL even after all the alterations printing of the array moreThanEightySet is not happening

Comment: @anveshmydg : I have done basic changes in your code .As of now , it is working fine .How should I provide you that code ?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an excercise from chapter 1, I tried to find a solution with only the tools learned until that point. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input of chars in the line */
#define MAXTEXT 50000 /* input maximun of chars in the text */
#define MINLINE 80 /* minimun input to print */

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
int concat(char line[], char base[], int position, int len);

main(){
    int len;
    int maxLine;    

    char line[MAXLINE];
    char base[MAXLINE];
    int pos;
    pos = 0;
    while ( (len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > MINLINE) //Testing if the line has more than 80 chars
            pos = concat(line, base, pos, len);
    printf("Text:\n%s", base);
    return 0;
}

/* Concat the lines */
/* Keeps track of the postion */
int concat(char line[], char base[], int position, int len){
    int i ;
    for (i = 0; i< len && position < MAXTEXT ; i++){
        base[position] = line[i];
        position++;
    }
    return position;
}

/*getline: read a line, return length*/
int getline(char s[], int lim){
    int c , i;
    for (i = 0 ; i <= lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        s[i] = c;
    if ( c == '\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

I just stored the text in a char array ("base" in the code). To achieve this it was necessary to concatenate the lines (with the function "concat") and track the position to keep adding the lines. This way the code allows to control wich lines to add and which not.

PS: I suggest to change the 80 in MINLINE definition for a lower number to test it easily.

Answer (score 0):

With Reference to my comment number #1 :

I have edited my code (as suggested in my previous comment ) .Here is the complete working code .
I personally feel this code can further be improved .

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxWordLength 100

int getline1(char _line[], int _maxWordLength);
void copy(char to[maxWordLength][maxWordLength], char from[], int _rowCounter);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char line[maxWordLength]={0};
    char moreThanEightySet[maxWordLength][maxWordLength]={0};                                       //2D array to store lines with characters more than eighty   

    int r_length;  
    int rowCounter = 0;
    int i;

    while((r_length = getline1( line, maxWordLength)) > 0)
    {   
        if(r_length > 80)
            copy( moreThanEightySet, line, rowCounter);

            rowCounter++; //right place to increment it
    }

    for(i = 0; i < rowCounter; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %s", moreThanEightySet[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
int getline1(char _line[], int _maxWordLength)                                                  //reads line inputs and returns the number of characters
{
    int  i;
    char c;

    for(i = 0 ; i < _maxWordLength - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' ; i++)
    {

        _line[i] = c;
    }

    if(c == '\n')
    {
        _line[i + 1] = '\n' ;
    }
    if(c == '\0')
    {
       _line[i + 1] = 0; ; //I personally feel this condition is not required 
    }

    return i;
}
void copy(char to[maxWordLength][maxWordLength], char from[], int _rowCounter)  
{

    int i=0;
    while((to[_rowCounter][i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
    to[_rowCounter][i]=0;    
}
```

Please note , for some reasons you have below condition in your code .

```
if(r_length > 80)
                copy( moreThanEightySet, line, rowCounter);
```

which means copy from "line" to "moreThanEightySet" untill and unless input is greater than 80 words .Please consider it while giving input else "copy" will not be called and hence you will end up printing nothing inside "moreThanEightySet" .
Let me know if you are facing any other problem .

Comment: if its not a problem can you tell me how to improve the code i want to get better

Comment: and i also found another problem i prints random ascii characters sometimes at the end of few lines while printing.

Comment: I have given some comments @anveshmydg in my last answer .Hope that will help .Comments are incorporated within the code itself .

Comment: yes i did edit the code based on few comments you can check the code in the question i went and updated it

Comment: @anveshmydg :  two things , first inside main ,char line[maxWordLength]={0};
    char moreThanEightySet[maxWordLength][maxWordLength]={0}; i.e. intiliaze the complete array with zero .second , now since array is initislized to zero , remove  _line[i + 1] = '\0' ;
from getline1()

Comment: @anveshmydg: also , remove this condition if(c == '\n')
    {
        _line[i + 1] = '\n' ;
    }
instead run the for loop till "i < _maxWordLength " instead of i < _maxWordLength - 1 . it will do the trick :)

Comment: @anveshmydg : In one of ur comment , you talked about deleting the question .Please do not delete the question as it would be helpful for some other guys who faced similar problem .hope you would understand !